# How to send email from GoDaddy mail server

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

In my Laravel project I can't send mail from my GoDaddy mail account. I have provided all the needed value in files but mail not send.

**Here is my `.env` file**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=hostdetails
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=test@ezmoverandrental.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=testpass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

**controller**

```
public function estimation_form_submit_confirm()
{
    Mail::send(new SendMail());
}
```

**App/Mail/SendMail.php**

```
namespace App\Mail;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Http\request;

class SendMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function build(request $request)
    {
        return $this->view('mail',['name'=>'raff'])->to('support@gmail.com')->from('info@domainName.com');
    }
}
```

No error shown in `log` file also.

Where else I need to change in my code !!!

Anybody Help Please ?

Answer (score 0):

========================================================================
1. please used php artisan config:clear or php artisan config:cache to update you configuration

2. you are using queue so you need to run queue listner. please run php artisan queue:work

Note:-
Note: Once you close the terminal, the queue will stop working. If you want the queue to continue listening, you can run the following command in your Linux terminal:

nohup php artisan queue:work &

========================================================================

If you want to send a simple mail you can send without queues

1. with a blade file

```php
Mail::send('auth.emails.verify', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
              $message->to($data['email'])
                      ->subject('Verify your email address');
});



2. without a blade

Mail::send([], [], function ($message) use ($data) {
                $message->to($data['email'])
                        ->subject('Verify your email address')
                        ->setBody('<h1>Verify Your Email Address</h1><p>You registration is successful verify your email before proceeding by clicking the link below. </p><p><a href="">Click here to activate your account .</a></p>', 'text/html');  
 });


3. Or simply text mail

 Mail::raw('Your Text', function ($message) use ($data)  {
              $message->to($data['email'])
                ->subject('Verify your email address');
  });
```